# perl how to find time for http request completion

Tags: perl, mechanize, www-mechanize

I have a form to fill and on submit, it will return result.
Now, i want to calculate the time taken to fulfill my request ie time when result got displayed-time i clicked submit.

I have no idea, how to do so. Please feel free to use any module. I dont know which parameter to use to check that response page is displayed. I have used reading title of result page just to check that response is displayed correctly.

my code:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$m->get( "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" );
$m->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    fields    => { search  => 'honey', },
    button    => 'go'  #my time1 should start at this moment
);
#my time 2 should be recorded as soon as result page is displayed, i dont know what to use to get this time
$tmp=$m->title;
print "$tmp\n";
```

Comment: You may want to check https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Timer

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WWW::Mechanize::Timed](http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Timed)

Comment: suppose my result page took 5 second, will $tmp=$m->title wait for 5 second and then print $tmp, or what would be the behaviour

Comment: See the documentation for available methods, I think you need `client_total_time`.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the time when you submit the request and also immediately after result got displayed in the script using time function. Then difference of both can give you the required time taken for the request.

Otherwise you can also try WWW::Mechanize::Timed as Pathak suggested.

Comment: suppose my result page took 5 second, will $tmp=$m->title wait for 5 second and then print $tmp, or what would be the behaviour